# Pandas dataframe indexes

Tags: python, pandas, text-classification

Lets say I am working with a dataset which has 10 columns. 
Now, the Label column for my 'Y' is 1. 
How do I set my X and Y. 
This is what I have done so far.

```
array = dataframe. values
X = array[:,0:2:32]   #I know this isn't the right way to do this.  
Y = array[:,1]
```

Yes, we can assign names to columns and omit the column with name=label, but I am trying to find a straight forward approach based on indexes. Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Y = df.loc[:,1].values
cols = list(df.loc[:,:0]) + list(df.loc[:,2:32])
X = df[cols].values
```